# k8s - Why we need ReplicaSet when we have Deployments

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I am new to kubernetes and microservices, there are 2 objects, [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/).

I can't wrap my head around even after reading its documentations and other articles.

If we have `Deployments`, why do we need a `ReplicaSet` because you can specify the replicaset in the `Deployment`. And when i delete the pods, new pods will be spawned based on the replicaset, just like the deployments.

Like what is the actual use-case where we only need `ReplicaSet` but not `Deployments`

Comment: this might help you a bit https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526877/5305962

Answer (score 16):

Deployment works one level above ReplicaSet object. Deployment is recommended for application services.

With deployment you should be able to do rolling upgrade or rollback. You can update image from v1 to v2.

With ReplicaSet you define number of replicas you want to run. For a particular service. You would have those many replicas running.

Comment: And underneath deployment also uses the replica set feature to spawn off the pods. It adds revision control to that.. which creates new replica sets based on the changes.

Comment: But deployment also has `replicas` param to control replication of pods. In which case should I choose ReplicaSet over Deployment?

Answer (score 3):

deployment is for stateless application and we can update our application by it.
by replicaset we can not update our application easily and it has a lot of work to do to update our application.