# What is the division of responsibilities between Deployments and ReplicaSets in a rolling update?

Tags: kubernetes

When updating my deployment to use a new version of my application, a new ReplicaSet is created and the previous ReplicaSet is scaled down as the new one scales up. What is the separation of concerns between the Deployment and the two ReplicaSets during this process?

Am I correct in assuming that it's the Deployment that's gradually changing the number of desired replicas for the two ReplicaSets as the update progresses?

Answer (score 0):

A ReplicaSet ensures that a number of Pods is created in a cluster. The pods are called replicas and are the mechanism of availability in Kubernetes. But changing the ReplicaSet will not take effect on existing Pods, so it is not possible to easily change, for example, the image version.

A deployment is a higher abstraction that manages one or more ReplicaSets to provide controlled rollout of a new version. When the image version is changed in the Deployment, a new ReplicaSet for this version will be created with initially zero replicas. Then it will be scaled to one replica, after that is running, the old ReplicaSet will be scaled down. (The number of newly created pods, the step size so to speak, can be tuned.)

**Below explains about the division of responsibilities between Deployments and ReplicaSets in a rolling update?**

Deployment resources makes it easier for updating your pods to a newer version.

As per question lets assume,  ReplicaSet-A for controlling your pods, then You wish to update your pods to a newer version, now you should create Replicaset-B, scale down ReplicaSet-A and scale up ReplicaSet-B by one step repeatedly (This process is known as **rolling update**). Although this does the job, it's not a good practice and it's better to let K8S do the job.

A **Deployment resource** does this automatically without any human interaction and increases the abstraction by one level.

Note: Deployment doesn't interact with pods directly, it just does rolling update using ReplicaSets

Refer this [Replica set doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) and  [Deployment doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

Comment: Thank you for summarizing. So I'm correct in assuming it's the Deployment that adjusts ReplicaSets' settings for desired number of Pods, and the ReplicaSets creating/terminating Pods accordingly? The Kubernetes documentation is a bit confusing about this btw. "The Deployment creates three replicated Pods" kind of reads like Deployments are interacting with Pods directly.

Comment: Hang on, the above answer is copypasted from the Kubernetes docs and [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70547692/217649) without explicitly answering the question: is it the Deployment that scales the ReplicaSets' desired number of pods, or do the ReplicaSets scale the desired number of pods themselves? As for my remark about the Kubernetes documentation: I submitted a clarification that got accepted and is now published.