# Kubernetes: Why do multiple ReplicaSets appear in deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

In my `Deployment`, i specify 2 replicas for my application, but when i look at the result generated by kubernetes, it has 3 `ReplicaSet`, in my `Deployment` i don't specify anything related to `ReplicaSet`, why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does [Kubernetes: what's the difference between Deployment and Replica set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448131/kubernetes-whats-the-difference-between-deployment-and-replica-set) answer your question?  The question itself isn't quite the same but a couple of the answers do describe this relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are previous revisions of your deployment. Notice the little "rev1", "rev2" labels. Kubernetes retains old replicaSets, per default 10 revisions are stored.

Only the latest revision has your two pod `replicas` in the `replicaSet`. You can set the cleanup policy using `.spec.revisionHistoryLimit` according to the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#clean-up-policy).